# Confidence Intervals Variograms

Tags: r, confidence-interval, gstat

I am currently using the gstat package to create variograms of oil and gas production in counties in West Virginia.

Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qewrgar62r30fh3/AADihHPJDaz14kMyU166GEM4a?dl=0) to my dataset of SpatialPointsDataFrame and the code to produce a variogram is below

```
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)
prod_wv = readOGR(dsn = "~/variogram_wv", layer = "variogram_wv")
wv.vgm = variogram(log(BOE + 0.0001) ~ 1, data = prod_wv, 
               prod_wv2, cutoff = cf, width = cf/width_num)
wv.fit = fit.variogram(wv.vgm, vgm("Sph"))
plot(wv.vgm, wv.fit)
```

I would like to add a 95% confidence band to this variogram. Is there a function to do this? Is there another way to give an indication of precision?

Comment: Please edit to give some code that generates a variogram - use random data or example data sets if possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I've updated my question